# How to send and receive strings through TCP connection using kotlin

Tags: android, sockets, kotlin, tcp

I have a TCP Server on Windows, and I want to send and receive text strings between the server and my Android device.

I spent alot of time searching for an example using Kotlin but I didn't find any useful code, so I'm now only able to create the socket and connect.

```
fun connect() {
    try{
        val soc = Socket("192.168.1.5", 1419)
        val dout = DataOutputStream(soc.getOutputStream())
        dout.writeUTF("1")

        dout.flush()
        dout.close()
        soc.close()
    }
    catch (e:Exception){
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please elaborate your question? You may also find this useful: [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @user2340612 Thanks , i'm simply want to make a TCP Client using Kotlin, (connect to server , send and receive packets(in separated threads)) i can only connect and i didn't find a single post on SO showing how to do it in Kotlin all available codes are in Java

Comment: It works like java's `java.net.socket` for [kotlin tcp](https://sylhare.github.io/2020/04/07/Kotlin-tcp-socket-example.html). Or you can use ktor.

Answer (score 17):

You can check this simple example. Hope it'll help you!

**Server:**

```
fun main() {
    val server = ServerSocket(9999)
    println("Server running on port ${server.localPort}")
    val client = server.accept()
    println("Client connected : ${client.inetAddress.hostAddress}")
    val scanner = Scanner(client.inputStream)
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        println(scanner.nextLine())
        break
    }
    server.close()
}
```

**Client:**

```
fun main() {
    val client = Socket("127.0.0.1", 9999)
    client.outputStream.write("Hello from the client!".toByteArray())
    client.close()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your code , but this do the same as my code (connect and send packet)

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't get your question right. Your question is "How to send and receive strings through TCP connection using Kotlin" In the code snippet that I sent you the client is sending a string ("Hello from the client") the server which receives it and prints to the console.

Could you elaborate a bit on your question, such as I can update my code snippet?

Answer (score 5):

You can also do it with [ktor](https://ktor.io/), it's a kotlin based asynchronous framework. It uses coroutines natively which allow concurrency.

Use Kotlin 1.4 and ktor 1.6.0, add it to your `build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.32"
}

dependencies {
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:1.6.0")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-network:1.6.0")
}
```

Then you can use the [sockets](https://ktor.io/docs/servers-raw-sockets.html), it's still a bit experimental but it's getting there, with newer version `ktor-network` is now necessary.

Here is the code:

**Server:**

```kotlin
suspend fun server() {
    val server = aSocket(ActorSelectorManager(Executors.newCachedThreadPool().asCoroutineDispatcher())).tcp()
        .bind(InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 2323))
    println("Server running: ${server.localAddress}")
    val socket = server.accept()
    println("Socket accepted: ${socket.remoteAddress}")
    val input = socket.openReadChannel()
    val output = socket.openWriteChannel(autoFlush = true)
    val line = input.readUTF8Line()

    println("received '$line' from ${socket.remoteAddress}")
    output.writeFully("$line back\r\n".toByteArray())
}
```

**Client:**

```kotlin
suspend fun client() {
    val socket = aSocket(ActorSelectorManager(Dispatchers.IO)).tcp()
        .connect(InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 2323))
    val input = socket.openReadChannel()
    val output = socket.openWriteChannel(autoFlush = true)

    output.writeFully("hello\r\n".toByteArray())
    println("Server said: '${input.readUTF8Line()}'")
}
```

**Run them both:**

```kotlin
fun main() {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch { server() }
    runBlocking { client() }
}
```

When you run them, the client will send a message, the server will respond and you should see something like this:

```
Server running: /127.0.0.1:2323
Socket accepted: /127.0.0.1:56215
received 'hello' from /127.0.0.1:56215
Server said: 'hello back'
```

Find more example on their documentation [simple echo server](https://ktor.io/docs/servers-raw-sockets.html#simple-echo-server)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 important things based on my experiment:

1. get permission in AndroidManifest.xml

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
2. create the socket from a background thread, the following works for me:

```
    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute {
        val socket = Socket("192.168.0.15", 50000)
        val scanner = Scanner(socket.getInputStream())
        val printWriter = PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream())
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "${ scanner.nextLine() }")
        }
    }
```

This is the [source code in GitHub](https://github.com/zhijunsheng/chess-kotlin-andr).
There is a video of [my experiment](https://youtu.be/Peme9z4EIUo).