# Kotlin Client send and receive image from Linux python3 socket Server

Tags: python, kotlin, sockets

I'm trying to send and receive Image with Socket connect
However, the string between the client and the server can be exchanged, but it does not proceed from exchanging images.

This is My Kotlin Client code

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    Client().start()

}



class Client : Thread()
{
    var readImage = ReadImage()
    override fun run(){
        try{
            var socket = Socket("35.216.104.58",3000)
            var input = socket.getInputStream()
            var dis = DataInputStream(input)

            var output = socket.getOutputStream()
            var dos = DataOutputStream(output)
            var data  = getImageByte(readImage.setImage(0))
            dos.write(data)

            dos.close()
            output.close()
            socket.close()



        }catch (e: Exception){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }


    }

  }
}
```

and this is My Python3 Code

```
import socket
import cv2

ip = ''
port = 3000

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET)
server_socket.bind((ip,port))
server_socket.listen(1)

print('Waiting Client...')

client_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()
print('Connet Client!!')

data = client_socket.recv(1024)
encoded_img = np.fromstring(data,dtype = np.uint8)
image = cv2.imdecode(encoded_img,cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

How can I send and receive images between clients and servers?

Comment: Neither your kotlin code nor your python code actually do any sending or receiving of anything.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you are not sending any data, just creating a connection.

You can refer to this example of how to send data from kotlin: [How to send and receive strings through TCP connection using kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56535473/how-to-send-and-receive-strings-through-tcp-connection-using-kotlin)

And this example of how to receive data in python: https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#example

Comment: Thanks for your answer, The code above confirms that the string data is sent to the server and then connected, and the string data is deleted. What I want to know is how to send the client's image file to Python server and get it back.
The code has been modified to send the image from the client to the server. Please check if this code is correct.